# boxplotting multiple features

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

Can anyone please help me plot a boxplot using seaborn/pandas/matplotlib that represents 3 features: `customer_type`, `(departure_delay, aarrival_delay)` and `satisfaction`? This is the data set:

[image: csv-dataset]

I want it to look like this:

[image: handwritten-graph-boxplot]

I am trying this:

```
 plt.figure(figsize = (15,8))
 sns.boxplot(satis_df['customer_type'], 
 satis_df['departure_delay'], 
          satis_df['departure_delay'], 
 satis_df['arrival_delay'])
 plt.title('Figure 7: Boxplot', fontsize = 15)
 plt.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code:

```
boxplot = satis_df.boxplot(by=['customer_type'], column=['departure_delay_in_minutes', 'arrival_delay_in_minutes'], figsize=(15, 8), rot=45)
```

###### But you have to encode "customer_types" values into numeric ones first. (e.g. Loyal Customer = 1, disloyal customer = 0)

For more instructions, you may check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html).

Comment: Thanks vey much for trying, but i am getting this error:
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: @CAPTAINusMAN This error happens because the values of "customer_type" are strings not numeric. Check my updated answer.